# What does tf.gather_nd intuitively do?

Tags: tensorflow

Can you intuitively explain or give more examples about `tf.gather_nd` for indexing and slicing into high-dimensional tensors in Tensorflow?

I read the [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd), but it is kept quite concise that I find myself hard to follow the function's concept.

Comment: You may need this tutorial: https://riptutorial.com/tensorflow/example/29069/how-to-use-tf-gather-nd

Answer (score 32):

Ok, so think about it like this:

You are providing a list of index values to index the provided tensor to get those slices. The first dimension of the indices you provide is for each index you will perform. Let's pretend that tensor is just a list of lists.

[[0]] means you want to get one specific slice(list) at index 0 in the provided tensor. Just like this:

```
[tensor[0]]
```

[[0], [1]] means you want get two specific slices at indices 0 and 1 like this:

```
[tensor[0], tensor[1]]
```

Now what if tensor is more than one dimensions? We do the same thing:

[[0, 0]] means you want to get one slice at index [0,0] of the 0-th list. Like this:

```
[tensor[0][0]]
```

[[0, 1], [2, 3]] means you want return two slices at the indices and dimensions provided. Like this:

```
[tensor[0][1], tensor[2][3]]
```

I hope that makes sense. I tried using Python indexing to help explain how it would look in Python to do this to a list of lists.

Answer (score 4):

You provide a tensor and indices representing locations in that tensor. It returns the elements of the tensor corresponding to the indices you provide.

EDIT: An example

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
y = tf.gather_nd(x, [[1,1],[1,2]])
print(sess.run(y))
```

> [5, 6]

Comment: Could you elaborate or provide some examples? Sounds like the OP was frustrated the the API docs were too concise. I'm not sure this adds that much to the existing answer. It could be a better quick explanation but it's a bit hard to understand without referencing other explanations/resources, especially if you are unfamiliar with the API.